# MySQL - how to select consecutive rows depends of data

Tags: mysql, select, rows

I have a simple select from my table, where `id_usu_detalle=80` :

**log**:

[image]

How can i make a select with consecutive `log_estado 0, 1, 0, 1` , like this:

```
log_id   |   id_usu_detalle     |     log_estado     |      log_horafecha
  1775   |       80             |        0           |    2014-07-08 15:20:51    
  1774   |       80             |        1           |    2014-07-08 15:20:31    
  1513   |       80             |        0           |    2014-07-04 10:19:34  
  1512   |       80             |        1           |    2014-07-04 10:18:53
  1483   |       80             |        0           |    2014-07-03 18:37:45    
  1482   |       80             |        1           |    2014-07-03 18:36:16
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Probably. What problem did you encounter when you tried? And what did you try?

Comment: try `ORDER BY log_id`, the log-estado appears in 0 and 1 pairs relative to their log_id

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 
1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 
2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this? i haven't tested it yet but I think that'll work

```
SELECT 
    log_id, id_usu_detalle, log_horafecha, log_estado
FROM
    (SELECT 
        log_id,
        id_usu_detalle,
        log_horafecha,
        log_estado,
        IF(@A = log_estado, 5, 0) AS counter,
        @A:=log_estado
    FROM log
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A:=10000) AS t) AS temp
WHERE counter = 0;
```